# Why Task.WaitAll(); doesnt wait?

Tags: c#, html

Im creating simple website scrape tool.I scrape name of the site and link and after that i will save it to txt file.
My problem is that after using Task.WaitAll(); my console app thread run writeFile() and after that run all Tasks.
My code

```
static void Main(string[] args){


        Console.WriteLine("Enter count of data!");



        taskz = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            getSiteAsync();

        }

        var count = taskz.Count;
        Task.WaitAll(taskz.ToArray());

        writeFile();//This method gets execute before get links
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

getSite();

```
public  static async Task getSiteAsync(){

        var a = new Task(async () =>
        {
        back:
            String temp = "";

            var web = new HttpClient();

            string url = "Random Links from web uploaded from file";

            HttpResponseMessage data = await web.GetAsync(url);

            temp = data.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString();



            if (resources.Contains(temp) == false)
            {
                resources.Add(temp);//Add to list link
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                goto back;
            }
        });
        taskz.Add(a);
        a.Start();
    }
```

Comment: [You should NOT be creating tasks manually pretty much ever.  *TL;DR: Do not use Task or Task<T> constructors.*.](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html)

Comment: Where is `count` defined?  What is `resources`?  Why are you calling the same method in a loop with no change in state?  And why on earth would you be using `goto`?  Are you sure you don't have an infinite `goto` loop?  Why is `getSiteAsync` itself `async`?  Why are you manually creating `Task` objects?  Why not just have `getSiteAsync` itself be the asynchronous operation and in your top-level logic make a collection of those to await collectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing to understand with your current code is that you are waiting on the wrong thing (note that the IDE warned you about this - note the squiggly line under `getSiteAsync`).

You are **not** `WaitAll` the `Task`s you explicitly created. You are `WaitAll` on the 'implicit' `Task`s being created behind the scenes due to your use of `async` in the function declaration. And those implicit `Task`s (which are in no way related to your `a` `Task`) are already finished executing by the time you hit `Task.WaitAll`.

A tactical fix would be:

```
public static Task getSiteAsync(){

    var a = new Task(async () =>
    {
    back:
        String temp = "";

        var web = new HttpClient();

        string url = "Random Links from web uploaded from file";

        HttpResponseMessage data = await web.GetAsync(url);

        temp = data.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString();



        if (resources.Contains(temp) == false)
        {
            resources.Add(temp);//Add to list link
            Console.WriteLine(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            goto back;
        }
    });
    taskz.Add(a);
    return a;
}
```

Note, you should consider some wider rethinking of your approach. As an example, you may want to avoid [`Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) altogether (this may involve using `async` but **not** `Task.Run`). You may want to avoid using `goto`. You should definitely avoid writing to `resources` or `taskz` in separate threads (since neither are thread-safe).

Additionally, your code is returning:

```
temp = data.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString();
```

If the only thing you are interested in is the URL, then there is no need to do the web request at all. You could avoid the use of `async / await`, `Task`, `HttpClient` etc etc. You should just add the URL directly to the `List` in a synchronous way (since adding strings to a list is very fast).